# Get-ADUser not functioning correctly

Tags: scripting, active-directory, output, powershell-2.0

I've created a script that lists all users in a OU that are NOT a member of a certain group. This saves the results into a text file. I thought this was working fine until I took a username from the text file and searched it in Active Directory. Turned out the user was a member of the group I was trying to filter out. Here is the code -

```
Get-ADUser  -SearchBase "OU=Users 2004,OU=Cyngor,DC=gwynedd,DC=rhwydwaith"  -Filter {( memberof -ne "CN=CTX AppSense,OU=Rheoli,OU=Grwpiau,OU=TC Enviroment,DC=gwynedd,DC=rhwydwaith")}  -Properties Name | select Name  | Export-CSV "C:\Users.txt"
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working correctly. Any suggestions out there?

Thanks.

Comment: if the user is a member of another group memberof will neverbe equal to "CN=CTX AppSense,OU=Rheoli,OU=Grwpiau,OU=TC Enviroment,DC=gwynedd,DC=rhwydwaith"

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memberOf` is a multi-valued attribute, i.e. a list of distinguished names. Use the `-notcontains` operator to check if does not contain a particular distinguished name:

```psh
$ou = 'OU=Users 2004,OU=Cyngor,DC=gwynedd,DC=rhwydwaith'
$dn = 'CN=CTX AppSense,OU=Rheoli,OU=Grwpiau,OU=TC Enviroment,DC=gwynedd,DC=rhwydwaith'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties Name, MemberOf |
  ? { $_.MemberOf -notcontains $dn } |
  select Name  |
  Export-Csv 'C:\Users.txt' -NoType
```

Note that a user's primary group is not listed in the `memberOf` attribute. If the code should also handle primary groups you need to add a check for that:

```psh
$ou = 'OU=Users 2004,OU=Cyngor,DC=gwynedd,DC=rhwydwaith'
$dn = 'CN=CTX AppSense,OU=Rheoli,OU=Grwpiau,OU=TC Enviroment,DC=gwynedd,DC=rhwydwaith'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties Name, MemberOf |
  ? { $_.MemberOf -notcontains $dn -and $_.PrimaryGroup -ne $dn } |
  select Name  |
  Export-Csv 'C:\Users.txt' -NoType
```

Comment: Still seems to be the same. Returning names that are in the group im trying to filter out.

Comment: this should work. Double check your group DN (missing `n` here ? : TC Enviroment )

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake. But no change in the results

Comment: @user3853001 Do the accounts in question have the group defined as their primary group?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No their primary group is Domain Users

Comment: @user3853001 Then the above code should work. Please provide evidence.

Comment: @Thanks for the help. I cannot post things such as usernames because they are confidential data. I will mess around with it to see if I can get this to work

Comment: Working now. there was another eror further down the script. Thanks!